# CSS Hover Not Working on Transformed Elements

Tags: html, css, hover, transform

I'm trying to have a skewed element change size on hover but for whatever reason, the elements only change whenever the mouse is about 200px below where it should be. I'm guessing this is either happening because of the way I transformed the elements or because of the way I positioned them on the page.

Code below

```css
.layers {
    margin: 150px 150px;
    height: 500px !important;
    width: 500px !important;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera  */
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.layer img {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(75deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera  */
    transform: rotateX(75deg);
    display: inline;
    transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}

.layer:hover img {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 65px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 65px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 65px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    height: 510px;
    width: 510px;
    transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}

.layer1 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}

.layer2 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 450px;
}

.layer3 {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layers">
                   <div class="layer1 layer">
                       <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="">
                   </div><!-- layer1 -->
                   <div class="layer2 layer">
                       <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="">
                   </div><!-- layer2 -->
                   <div class="layer3 layer">
                       <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="">
                   </div><!-- layer3 -->
               </div><!-- layers -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the `transform: rotateX(75deg);` on `.layer` instead of its child image, like so:

```css
.layers {
    margin: 150px 150px;
    height: 500px !important;
    width: 500px !important;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera  */
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.layer {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(75deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera  */
    transform: rotateX(75deg);
}


.layer img {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
    display: inline;
    transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}

.layer:hover img {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 65px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 65px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 65px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    height: 510px;
    width: 510px;
    transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}

.layer1 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}

.layer2 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 450px;
}

.layer3 {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layers">
                   <div class="layer1 layer">
                       <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="">
                   </div><!-- layer1 -->
                   <div class="layer2 layer">
                       <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="">
                   </div><!-- layer2 -->
                   <div class="layer3 layer">
                       <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="">
                   </div><!-- layer3 -->
               </div><!-- layers -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `perspective: 1000px` with `transform: perspective(1000px)`

```css
.layers {
    margin: 150px 150px;
    height: 500px !important;
    width: 500px !important;
    //-webkit-perspective: 1000px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera  */
    transform: perspective(1000px);
}

.layer img {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(75deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera  */
    transform: rotateX(75deg);
    display: inline;
    transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}

.layer:hover img {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 65px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 65px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 65px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    height: 510px;
    width: 510px;
    transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}

.layer1 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}

.layer2 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 450px;
}

.layer3 {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layers">
                   <div class="layer1 layer">
                       <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="">
                   </div><!-- layer1 -->
                   <div class="layer2 layer">
                       <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="">
                   </div><!-- layer2 -->
                   <div class="layer3 layer">
                       <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="">
                   </div><!-- layer3 -->
               </div><!-- layers -->
```

Explanation from [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/):

> [...] the perspective property doesn't affect how the element is
>   rendered; it simply enables a 3D-space for children elements. This is
>   the main difference between the transform: perspective() function and
>   the perspective property. The first gives element depth while the
>   later creates a 3D-space shared by all its transformed children.

Comment: hmm, this didn't seem to change anything for me. In the snippet you provided it didn't change anything either.